# Rotate python logs at 12am midnight every day?

Tags: python, datetime, logging, cron

I'm using the `daiquiri` logging library in a simple python script (love it so far!). Out of the box it offers a timed rotating file option that I'd like to set to rotate every 24 hrs at midnight base on the machines time.  Under the hood it would take direction from `datetime`, so I guess really my question is how do I use datetime to specify 12am each night?

This is an example from daiquiri docs, and I'll need to adjust `interval=datetime.timedelta(1)` accordingly but I dont know where to start.

```
daiquiri.output.TimedRotatingFile(
        filename="logs.log", 
        program_name=None, 
        formatter=daiquiri.formatter.JSON_FORMATTER,
        level=logging.DEBUG, 
        interval=datetime.timedelta(1), 
        backup_count=0
        ),
```

Comment: There is no 12am or 12pm, there is *certainly* no 12am midnight :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for this library, It looks like they hardcode it to disallow you from rolling over your logs at midnight, only at a specified interval starting when the program is run.

Why not use the standard python logging module package? It looks like most of the stuff in `daiquiri` just wraps the logging module, including the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. If you switch to this library, you just set the `interval` value to `'midnight'` and it will work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler